# What's the difference between "preposition" and "postposition" compared to "circumposition"?

Tags: grammar, terminology

How do a *preposition* and a *postposition* differ from a *circumposition*?
Are these three terms really used in schools, universities and "official classes" in general?
Is there someone who "officially" calls all three just *prepositions*, and says there are simply "different types" of prepositions?

Comment: Can you give example sentences of all three? In English, all you really ever care about are prepositions. The other two are kinda out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prepositions, postpositions, and circumpositions are three types of *adpositions* defined by where they occur relative to the element they govern:

Prepositions are placed *before* the element they govern: “**on** the ground”, “**without** any help”, etc. English employs mainly prepositions. (For this reason, some people use the term ‘preposition’ to refer to all kinds of adpositions, especially in English.)

Postpositions are placed *after* the element they govern: “his claims **notwithstanding**”, “the whole night **through**”, etc. English has a few of these, but they are limited in both number and use. Other languages use them more prolifically or, like Japanese, exclusively (“アメリカ**に**” *Amerika-**ni*** ‘in America’, “二時**から**八時**まで**” *niji-**kara** hachiji-**made*** ‘from two o’clock till eight o’clock’).

Circumpositions consist of two parts: one placed before the element they govern, and one placed after it: “**from** now **on**”, etc. These are quite rare in English (I can’t think of any other examples than this one, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition)), though they are quite common in languages that frequently use both prepositions and postpositions, such as Chinese.

The Wikipedia page linked to above has quite a thorough explanation of adpositions.

Comment: [wisegeek](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-circumposition.htm) also offers ***in** place **of**, **with** a mind **to** and **by** virtue **of**.*

Comment: I’m not sure I’d really count ‘in place of’ and ‘by virtue of’ as circumpositions. The ‘of’ here is really a preposition to the following element, marking a genitival relationship between it and ‘place/virtue’, and ‘in/by’ governs the entire prepositional phrase. Probably the same with ‘with a mind to’, come to think of it.

And ‘from now on’ isn’t that good either, truth be told, since ‘on’ there is more an adverb than an adposition.

Comment: @ Janus: Well, both you and wisegeek agree *circumpositions* are at the very least ***rare*** in English. Wisegeek also makes the point that this is largely because English *syntax* isn't particularly conducive to such formations. Which is probably why I don't really understand them - I can't even see why [**from** here **on in**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22from+here+on+in%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doesn't count as a ***three-word*** example (but I'm guessing it doesn't! :)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding officiality, the wikipedia article *[Adposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adposition)* suggests that indeed “Some linguists use the word "preposition" instead of "adposition" for all three cases”, the three cases being prepositions, postpositions, and circumpositions.

Note that a  *circumposition* has two parts and surrounds the complement, *ie* has one part per side.

The terms *preposition*, *postposition*, *circumposition*, and their hypernym *adposition* are in use in linguistics, where technical terms are needed for brief but accurate reference.

Comment: Though the term is used generally with this sense only in context; if the addressees understand the convention, that's OK. Otherwise, more precision may be required to avoid confusion. By the way, same prefixes, same senses, and same reference conventions for _prefix, postfix, circumfix,_ and _affix_.

Comment: Wouldn't *are in use **only** in linguistics...* be more accurate?